# mysql isam optimization for best performance

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, bulkinsert

I am using Mysql 5.2 to insert huge records ( almost a billion records)

I am using following settings .

Which parameters i can change to get BEST insert and Queries speed?

I will only create 5 tables and my queries are limitied to 10 containing multiple joins.

Following are the settings i am using:

```
back_log = 50

max_connections = 1024

max_connect_errors = 10

table_open_cache = 2048

max_allowed_packet = 16M

binlog_cache_size = 1M

max_heap_table_size = 64M

read_buffer_size = 2M

read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M

sort_buffer_size = 8M

join_buffer_size = 8M

thread_cache_size = 64

thread_concurrency = 24

query_cache_size = 0

query_cache_limit = 0

ft_min_word_len = 4

default_storage_engine = MYISAM

thread_stack = 192K

transaction_isolation = READ-COMMITTED

tmp_table_size = 64M

log_bin = mysql-bin

expire_logs_days = 7

max_binlog_size = 100M

binlog_format = mixed

slow_query_log

long_query_time = 2

server_id = 11

skip_external_locking

key_buffer_size = 32M

delay_key_write = all

bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M

myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M

**myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10G**

myisam_repair_threads = 2

myisam_recover

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 16M

**innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16G**

innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:32M;ibdata2:32M;ibdata3:32M;ibdata4:32M:autoextend

innodb_file_io_threads = 4

innodb_thread_concurrency = 24

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0

innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M

innodb_log_file_size = 256M

innodb_log_files_in_group = 3

innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90

innodb_doublewrite = 0

skip-innodb_doublewrite

innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120

[mysqldump]

quick

max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]

no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]

key_buffer_size = 512M

sort_buffer_size = 512M

read_buffer = 8M

write_buffer = 8M

[mysqlhotcopy]

interactive-timeout
```

Comment: This is probably a better fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com/